# Regex to Match Specific URL with Query String

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I'm trying to match a specific URL that allows for query strings. Basically I need the following to happen:

- `http://some.test.domain.com` - Pass
- `http://some.test.domain.com/` - Pass
- `http://some.test.domain.com/home` - Pass
- `http://some.test.domain.com/?id=999` - Pass
- `http://some.test.domain.com/home?id=888&rt=000` - Pass
- `http://some.test.domain.com/other` - Fail
- `http://some.test.domain.com/another?id=999` - Fail

Here is what I have so far:

```
var pattern = new RegExp('^(https?:\/\/some\.test\.domain\.com(\/{0,1}|\/home{0,1}))$');
if (pattern.test(window.location.href)){
    console.log('yes');   
}
```

The above code only works for the first three and not for the query strings. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain why those that pass pass and why those that fail fail?  What is the logic here?  Are only nothing and `/home` allowed?

Comment: @JamesMontagne I only want the first five conditions to work. Anything else should fail.

Comment: @progenhard Yes, I also need to get the top five links to pass.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A pattern like this should work (at least for your specific domain)

```
/^http:\/\/some\.test\.domain\.com(\/(home)?(\?.*)?)?$/
```

This will match a literal `http://some.test.domain.com` optionally followed by all of a literal `/`, optionally followed by a literal `home`, optionally followed by a literal `?` and any number of other characters.

You can test it [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5Ehttp://some%5C.test%5C.domain%5C.com%28/%28home%29?%28%5C?.%2a%29?%29?%24&input=http://some.test.domain.com%0Ahttp://some.test.domain.com/%0Ahttp://some.test.domain.com/home%0Ahttp://some.test.domain.com/?id=999%0Ahttp://some.test.domain.com/home?id=888&rt=000%0Ahttp://some.test.domain.com/other%0Ahttp://some.test.domain.com/another?id=999)

Comment: @progenhard It's not clear to me that OP cares about capturing groups, but sure, any of the groups could all be turned into non-capturing groups pretty easily (e.g. `…(?:\/(?:home)?(?:\?.*)?)?$/`)

Comment: The code uses `pattern.test`.  I can't think of any reason it would matter if groups are capturing or not.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a Regex, use an URL parser. You could use [`purl`](https://github.com/allmarkedup/purl)

Then, you'll do:

```
url = "http://some.test.domain.com/home" // Or any other
purl(url).attr('path')  // is equal to "home" here.
```

You'll just need to check `.attr('path')` against your accepted paths (seemingly `""`, `"/"`, and `"home"`).

---

Here's some sample output:

```
purl("http://some.test.domain.com/?qs=1").attr('path')
"/"
purl("http://some.test.domain.com/other").attr("path")
"/other"
purl("http://some.test.domain.com/home").attr("path")
"/home"
```

Comment: @Qtax Haha thanks, I was thinking in Python for some reason : l

Comment: @ThomasOrozco Thanks for the input, but I'm limited to jQuery 1.9

Comment: @SamG.Daniel Keep in mind that Purl is just one file that's 267 lines of code. Its not like it's a massive library you're pulling in.

Comment: This is an excellent resource! thanks for turning me onto this instead of REGEX (we have a list of 25 allowed urls for filesharing sites) especially when added into jQuery.validator.addMethod(), IMHO it should have been included in jQuery.validator